# A trigger to add 7 days to a date

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have a column start_week and another column end_week. I make a trigger where I set start_week set end_week in + 7days, but it doesn't work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_fin_semana UPDATE of fin_semana on fb_clients 
BEGIN
  UPDATE fb_clients SET fin_semana = 'select date('now','+6 day'), WHERE nombre=old.nombre; 
END;
```

the error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "select": syntax error
At line 1:
CREATE TRIGGER T_fin_semana UPDATE of fin_semana on fb_clients 
BEGIN
  UPDATE fb_clients SET fin_semana = select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_fin_semana AFTER UPDATE OF fin_semana ON fb_clients 
    BEGIN
     UPDATE fb_clients SET fin_semana = date('now','+6 day') WHERE nombre=old.nombre; 
     END;
```

That is you need

1. to specify one of:-

- `BEFORE`
- `AFTER`
- `INSTEAD OF`

before the triggering action *(UPDATE INSERT or DELETE)*, and

2. correct the syntax errors in the UPDATE as shown above.

- You can use `(SELECT date('now','+6 day'))` but there is no need for the SELECT as the expression is fine on it's own.

Tested Using :-

```
/* Test */
INSERT INTO fb_clients (fin_semana) VALUES('not set');
UPDATE fb_clients SET fin_semana = 'updated';
SELECT * FROM fb_clients;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

Comment: now don't have errors but in sql error log show this : (1) Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface. (, :0)

Comment: @KelvinJPS that is a different issue and will need another question as it's not SQLite related.

Comment: it is working , thank you for your help dude